# Javascript - If pop-up (by name) is open?

Tags: javascript, popup

How can you check to see if a pop-up is already open strictly by the original pop-up's name, and not URL, etc.

The pop-up is opened via window.open().

Comment: If your question has been answered, you should accept it as your answer. If your question hasn't been answered the way you expected, you should clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

Keep the handle to the window:

```
var popup = window.open( URL, name, features )
```

So later you can check whether it's closed by using it's "closed" property.

```
if (popup.closed) {
    // closed
}
else {
    // still open
}
```

You can see it working here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/windowclosed.htm

EDIT

You should be able to do just what Cheery said, but if you would like more detail, I tested this, and it works:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var popup;
      function openPopup() {
        popup = window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com", "so", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=300,height=300");
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <button onclick="openPopup()">open popup</button>
    <button onclick="checkIfPopupIsOpen()">check for popup</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function checkIfPopupIsOpen() {
        if (popup.closed) {
          alert("it's closed");
        }
        else {
          alert("it's still open");
        }
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I do this, it just brings up the same window, and refreshes it.

Comment: When I define the variable (handler), it immediately opens it up.

Comment: @GrayAdams `When I define the variable` because this method works with popups opened within the same page without its refresh.

Comment: @Cheery It is on the same page, just within a JS file at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @GrayAdams Open window, save handle into global variable as shown in the first listing of the answer. When you want to check the window use the second listing.